# Query MySQL database from a bash script

Tags: mysql, linux, bash, shell

I'm new to bash scripting and I am practicing with some simple scripts.  I am creating a script that connects to a MySQL database, executes a query and echo the results.
This is what I have so far but I am being given this frustrating error:

```
./testsql: line 22: syntax error near unexpected token `queryConfig="mysql -uroot -p1234 test"'
./testsql: line 22: `queryConfig="mysql -uroot -p1234 test"'
```

This is the function inside my script.

```
function testFunction{
queryConfig="mysql -uroot -p1234 test"
hello=`$queryConfig"SELECT * FROM test_accounts;"`
echo "Result = " $hello
}
```

Ok I know that ideally I should not pass the username and password into the script but rather use a config.sh which can then be included in the script.  Also it is not ideal to use the root.  But here the important thing is that I understand where is the sytax error and why is the interpreter complaining.
Once I get this work I can create a config.sh and variables accordingly.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
var=$(mysql database -u $user -p$password<<<"SELECT * FROM test_accounts")
```

Answer (score 0):

This error:

> ```
> ./testsql: line 22: syntax error near unexpected token `queryConfig="mysql -uroot -p1234 test"'
> ```

Says that line 22 of your Bash script has a syntax error (i.e. it isn't valid Bash). The parser doesn't think you can do a variable assignment here. But why?

The issue is in the line above:

> ```
> function testFunction{
> ```

Bash is very whitespace-sensitive, and you're missing a space between your function name and the `{` character. Try adding a space and you'll resolve this syntax error.

---

There are other issues in your script (beyond the security concerns you mention) that I'll touch on briefly:

- Avoid using backticks, prefer `$(...)` for [command substitution](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/commandsub.html). It's easier to read and works better when you start nesting substitutions inside each other.
- Pay attention to whitespace, e.g. your next line

  > ```
  > hello=`$queryConfig"SELECT * FROM test_accounts;"`
  > ```

  Will execute the command

  ```
  mysql -uroot -p1234 testSELECT * FROM test_accounts;
  ```

  Notice the `testSELECT` there - you're missing a space.
- Pay attention to quoting. [Quoting in Bash](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/quotingvar.html) is hard, but it's important to get right. There are some good [best-practices](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck#quoting) to internalize that makes working with quotes in Bash a lot easier.